# Element 'workOrder': No matching global declaration available for the validation root

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

My **XML** as below

```
<workOrder workOrderNumber="1005" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="conditionSurvey.load.tsd.xsd">
<link>
```

---

**XSD** as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb" xdb:storeVarrayAsTable="true" targetNamespace="http://iris/conditionSurvey/load/tsd" xmlns="http://iris/conditionSurvey/load/tsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://iris/conditionSurvey/load/tsd http://cdvdc2ora001:8080/public/xsd/conditionSurvey.load.tsd.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

When I try to validate my XML against my XSD it gives an error

> ERROR: Element 'workOrder': No matching global declaration available
>   for the validation root.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't give much XML or XSD for us to troubleshoot or use to reproduce, but it looks like your schema uses a targetNamespace of `http://iris/conditionSurvey/load/tsd` and your XML is not in a namespace. Try adding `xmlns="http://iris/conditionSurvey/load/tsd"` to the `workOrder` element in your XML.